# Elasticsearch self.published?

Tags: elasticsearch-rails

I am using `elasticsearch-rails gem` For my site i need to create custom callbacks. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#custom-callbacks
But i really confused by one thing. What means `if self.published?` on this code?
i try to use this for my models

```
after_commit on: [:update] do
  place.__elasticsearch__.update_document if self.published?
end
```

but for model in console i see `self.published? => false` but i don`t know what this means

Answer (score 0):

From the document of elasticsearch-rails.

> For ActiveRecord-based models, use the after_commit callback to protect your data against inconsistencies caused by transaction rollbacks:

I think it was used to make sure everything is updated successfully into database before we sync to elasticsearch server

Comment: thanks, but i confused, what is self.published?
i check elasticsearch repo and found published field, think this is custom solution, but this condition is confuses

Comment: i think it's function of ActiveRecord. I'm not sure.

Comment: me too, and that was my question